# Save image created by GD PHP on click of that Image

Tags: php, image, gd, href

I show an image in  tag which is created by GD PHP by merging two images.
Something like this

```
$('#output_images').append(<img src="MergeIcons.php?icon1='+firstIcon+'&icon2='+secondIcon+'" /></li>');
```

This outputs the image correctly, now I want to make this as a clickable image which on click downloads the image.

Something like

```
$('#output_images').append('<li><a href="DownloadNewIcon.php?file="MergeIcons.php?icon1='+firstIcon+'&icon2='+secondIcon+'"><img src="MergeIcons.php?icon1='+firstIcon+'&icon2='+secondIcon+'" /></a></li>');
```

I am not sure what should be the values for href? If I handle the download in different PHP file then what should be the file path?

My PHP code for merging two icons,

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the user download the file automatically, add this near the Content-Type header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $generateSomeFilename .'"');
```

This will cause most browsers to not output the image but immediately show the save as dialog.

Comment: I would first like to show the user and then let him download. There are multiple images which are listed and user can download any one of the list depending on his choice. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, as you showed in your own code: wrap the link to the script around img-elements with the output of the script.

The user will then see all the images and when he/she clicks on an image the image will automatically be saved/the save as dialog opens.

Comment: If I do that way, I can download the image on click but it contains errors, it cant be seen. My downloadNewIcon.php just does this header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($_GET['file'])."\";" );

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an event handler and call the PHP again:

```
var url = 'MergeIcons.php?icon1='+firstIcon+'&icon2='+secondIcon;
var img = $('<img>', {'src':url}).on('click', function()
{
    document.href = url + '&download=true';
});
$('#output_images').append(img);
```

Then, add the Content-Type header when you recieve the "download = true" paramater.

Comment: The Content-Type should be set always, no matter the context (show or download).